# Command to find and combine files matching a complex name pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, find

My Linux directory contains a dump of files and they look like:

```
EDW_Infile_ABC_Daily_Activity_20190204.csv
EDW_Infile_ABC_Daily_Activity.zip
EDW_Infile_PQRInc_Daily_Activity_20190204.csv
EDW_Infile_PQRInc_Daily_Activity_zip
EDW_Infile_ABC_Daily_Payment_20190204.csv
EDW_Infile_PQRInc_Daily_Payment_20190204.csv
EDW_Infile_ABC_Daily_Status_20190204.csv
EDW_Infile_PQRInc_Daily_Status_20190204.csv
```

These files follow few common name patterns such as

```
EDW_Infile_*<3 to 8 bytes company name>*_Daily_Activity_*YYYYMMDD*.csv
EDW_Infile_*<3 to 8 bytes company name>*_Daily_Payment_*YYYYMMDD*.csv
EDW_Infile_*<3 to 8 bytes company name>*_Daily_Status_*YYYYMMDD*.csv
```

How can I -

1) Find all files for all customers, for all dates, which follow the pattern EDW_Infile_*{3 to 8 bytes any name}*_Daily_Activity_*{Any Date}*.csv

2) Each file contains a header. How can I combine all of them into one file and have only one header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pushed my zsh knowledge a bit in order to answer more specifically, in case you weren't in control of the filenames and had files named like `EDQ_Infile_some uninteresting stuff here_Daily_Activity_junk here.csv` and so didn't want to use a `*` wildcard.

To gather the list of filenames ...

> which follow the pattern EDW_Infile_{3 to 8 bytes any name}_Daily_Activity_{Any Date}.csv

I would set up this extended_glob pattern in zsh (don't type the `$` -- that's the shell prompt):

```
$ set -o extended_glob
$ files=(EDW_Infile_?(#c3,8)_Daily_Activity_[[:digit:]](#c8).csv)
```

The pattern, apart from the plain text, is:

- `?` -- any (single) character
- `(#c3,8)` -- require between three and eight characters, inclusive
- `[[:digit:]]` -- require a digit
- `(#c8)` -- require eight of them

See the list with:

```
$ print -l $files
EDW_Infile_ABC_Daily_Activity_20190204.csv
EDW_Infile_PQRInc_Daily_Activity_20190204.csv
```

To then ...

> combine all of them into one file and have only one header

```
{ head -1 "${files[1]}"; for f in $files; do sed 1d "$f"; done; } > output.csv
```

This groups two commands and redirects their output to `output.csv`. The first command, `head`, takes the first line from the first file in the array; the second command then loops through all of the files and deletes the first line (default-printing the remainder to stdout).

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this

```
# collect all the "EDW_Infile_ABC" prefixes
declare -A prefix
for f in EDQ_Infile_*_Daily_Activity_*.csv; do
    p=${f%_*.csv}
    prefix[$p]=1
done

for p in "${!prefixes[@]}"; do
    awk 'NR==1 {print} FNR==1{next} {print}' "$p"_*.csv > "$p"_all.csv
    zip "$p".zip "$p"_all.csv
    rm  "$p"_all.csv
done
```

For bash, requires version 4 for associative arrays. Otherwise, we can work with positional parameters.